# Angularjs unit test with real backend

Tags: django, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a Django backend with REST and Angular frontend. So I want to test angular services on real data, not mocked. Is there any easy way to do it? Without selenium or thomething similar, just using karma and jasmine.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ngMockE2E:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend

this let you interact with a real backend without having to use protractor

Answer (score 1):

In Django/Angular project where I work we're using https://github.com/angular/protractor but it's based on Selenium and launches a browser instance.

I had a quick google and found this though:
http://www.tuesdaydeveloper.com/2013/06/angularjs-testing-with-karma-and-jasmine/

However I suspect that your desire to use 'real data, not mocked' is at odds with the nature of Karma+Jasmine.

Comment: Thanks. A already have common unit tests and selenium tests. I'm just want to find client-server interaction problems, when API changes. Selenium seems too unreliable and slow.